# What is the correct way to clear a class instance of its recursive pointers to a same class instance

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm building a reset function to a very simple octree class which goal is to reset all of the octree instances created by this same octree.

The `octree.h` class defines a public array of pointers like this

```
Octree *children[8];
bool subdivided; // true if has children
```

and this is the reset function in `octree.cpp`

```
void Octree::reset()
{
    if(subdivided)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            children[i]->reset();
            children[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

instances of the octree class are initiated using new in a class subdivision() function.

Everytime I run this code I get a exception thrown

> Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000

Which according to the call stack, comes from an insert() function called after the reset(), which should repopulate the tree.

What I understand is that the function that is causing the exception is trying to read the pointer (which is now NULL). I think this means my object is still there, but my pointer isn't. How do I recursively access and delete all my children ?

edit :

I solved it, the error was coming from the fact that I wasn't updating the isSubdivided variable and was only resetting the pointers not deleting the objects.

```
void Octree::reset()
{
    if(subdivided)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            children[i]->reset();
            delete children[i];
        }
        subdivided = false;
    }
}
```

The memory doesn't seem to leak anymore and there are no more thrown exceptions, thanks everyone :)

Comment: You're dereferencing a null pointer in an "unrelated function" - is this happening after `reset()` execution? Where are you allocating and freeing `Octree` instances?

Comment: sorry for my wording, the unrelated function I'm talking about is a function that inserts points into the octree and its children. That function is called after my reset() function to repopulate the octree once it has been emptied.

Comment: Can you post the code and traceback related to the error you're getting?

Comment: What was `children[i]` pointing to before?  Does it make sense that you set it to NULL?  How would the caller know what the original children nodes were? You could be leaking memory if they were allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct way to clear a class instance of its recursive pointers to a same class instance

It depends on what "clearing" means in the context.

---

> ```
> Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000
> ```
>
> Which according to the call stack, comes from an insert() function
>   called after the reset

`reset` sets the pointers to null. If `insert` indirects through those pointers, then behaviour of the program is undefined.

There are two potential solutions:

- Modify `insert` to behave correctly in case the pointers are null. Possibly by checking the nullity.
- Establish a class invariant that the pointers are never null. This implies that `reset` must be modified such that it doesn't leave those pointers null. This may be achieved by using a sentienl node instead of null to represent child of a leaf.

> I think this means my object is still there, but my pointer isn't.

The pointer is always in the array. Issue is what the pointer points to. In this case, it doesn't point to an object because it is null.

---

> instances of the octree class are initiated using new
>
> ```
> children[i]->reset();
> children[i] = NULL;
> ```

This here is a memory leak. The pointer to the object allocated with new was lost and can no longer be deleted.

---

> How do I recursively access and delete all my children ?

Use smart pointers. That way setting a child to null removes the ownership, and the child gets deleted.

Comment: thanks for clearing this out for me , this was really constructive. I've managed to solve it from there and edited my post with the solution

Comment: I haven't learned about smart pointers yet, but I'm going to read up on that straight away

Comment: @Asymetr Regarding your solution, now after `reset`, your array contains dangling pointers. There is no way for `insert` or any other function to determine whether they are valid. You'll probably need to reconsider what state you leave the object in the `reset` function.

Comment: my octree root naturally contains 8 dangling pointers ready to be instanced with subdivisions of octree's. the pointers of every children though should have been deleted in the delete children[i]; call, which means I shouldnt have 8^n dangling pointers. correct me if I'm wrong I really want to understand this fully